# passing an array from java to javascript using bean

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am trying to pass a String[] from a java class to a jsp file, i manage to pass a simple String, but i am stuck on this one for few days now. Can someone help me, i wold like the answer to be more detailed since i am new at this.

**Java class:**

```
public class UserArray extends Applet {

public String  javaArray [] =
        { "array 1", "array 2" , "array 3" };

public String [] getJavaArray() {
    return javaArray;
}
}
```

**JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sb" uri="/struts-bootstrap-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <jsp:useBean id ="array" class="eu.xyx.ztr.applet.UserArray"/>
</head>
<body>
   <h4>

  <jsp:getProperty name ="array" property="javaArray"/> 

 </h4>

</body>
```

So far i have maage to obtain the address of String[]. I just want to obtain the values of javaArray and if it is posible to obtain them in a form like this:

```
<script>

    function addrow(tableID){


        var numeuser=document.numeuser;

        var nume=["adrian","cristi","levi",numeuser];
        var prenume=["ric","dre","asd"];
        var email=["rew@td","qq@eqwq","ee@ew"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlet

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();  
    myArray.add("array 1");  
    myArray.add("array 2");  
    myArray.add("array 3");  
    request.setAttribute("myArray", myArray);  

    //then call jsp :   
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp");  
    rd.forward(request, response);  

}
```

jsp

```
  <body>
      <c:forEach var="myarr" items="${myArray}">     
        <c:out value="${myarr}" />      
      </c:forEach>   
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript library like google JSON or jackson JSON for the same
have a look at these links

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json/

Comment: can i do this whitout using JSON ?

Comment: yes you can do this without JSON ,you can use arraylist instead of String array.....

Comment: and that will give me an array in a javascript ?

Comment: no you can use it in your html form only. if you want to access array value in javascript then you should use JSON library. have look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: one more question, if i will write in my jsp your code it supose to display : array 1 array 2 array 3 ?